# Add values from different tables: Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm developing a database and I need to calculate available stock quantity.

I have `itemquantity` from stock table, `purchasequantity` from purchase tables and `salesquantity` from sales table.

I need to perform `itemquantity = itemquantity + purchasequantity - salesquantity`

I used `group by` and got the SUM values of `salesquantity` and `purchasequantity`.

I can't figure how to do the operation.

Comment: You'll probably want to use two joins that allow you to access all three tables at the same time. Something like `UPDATE stock_table AS stock INNER JOIN purchase_table AS purchase {join condition} INNER JOIN sales_table AS sales {join condition} set stock.itemquantity = stock.itemquantity + purchase.purchasequantity - sales.salesquantity WHERE {filter condition};` (modify this query to correspond to oracle syntax). If you require further assistance, please modify your question to show minimal code that you've tried so far together with expected outcome versus actual outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `MERGE INTO` statement for update like this. Hopefully you have proper columns to join.

```
MERGE INTO stock sr USING ( SELECT
    s.id_column,
    ( s.itemquantity + p.purchasequantity - s.salesquantity ) new_itemquantity
    FROM
    stock st
    JOIN purchase p ON st.join_column1 = p.join_column1
    JOIN sales s ON st.join_column2 = s.join_column2
)
m ON ( m.id_column = sr.id_column )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET sr.itemquantity = new_itemquantity;
```

Comment: Yes it does work, but on a single row, I instead wrote it in application logic, it's working fine now! Thanks